# Modelica model simulating successfully in OMEdit but not as FMU

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, fmi

I am trying to export and simulate a model with the CVode solver.
If I simulate the model in OMEdit (Windows) using CVode the simulation finishes successfully, even if I use something like a rectangular pulse as input. However, if I export the model as FMU (via omc on Linux) with CVode simulation flag I get the following Error after some time:

> [CVODE ERROR]  CVode   tout too close to t0 to start integration.
> fmi2DoStep: ##CVODE## -27 error occurred at time = 1.001.Traceback
> (most recent call last): 
> ... 
> Exception: fmi2DoStep failed with
> status 4.

To export the FMU I am using sundials-5.7.0 and for OMEdit OpenModelica1.17.0.

To my knowledge OMEdit uses the exact same solver, so I do not really understand why the simulation works in one case but not in the other.

Might this be related to running on Windows vs Linux, or does OMEdit maybe change some default simulation settings?

Any hints on possible causes and solutions are very welcome!

Notice:
The CVode settings when simulating the FMU look like this:
LOG_SOLVER        | info    | CVODE linear multistep method CV_BDF
LOG_SOLVER        | info    | CVODE maximum integration order CV_ITER_NEWTON
LOG_SOLVER        | info    | CVODE use equidistant time grid YES
LOG_SOLVER        | info    | CVODE Using relative error tolerance 1.000000e-06
LOG_SOLVER        | info    | CVODE Using dense internal linear solver SUNLinSol_Dense.
LOG_SOLVER        | info    | CVODE Use internal dense numeric jacobian method.
LOG_SOLVER        | info    | CVODE uses internal root finding method NO
LOG_SOLVER        | info    | CVODE maximum absolut step size 0
LOG_SOLVER        | info    | CVODE initial step size is set automatically
LOG_SOLVER        | info    | CVODE maximum integration order 5
LOG_SOLVER        | info    | CVODE maximum number of nonlinear convergence failures permitted during one step 10
LOG_SOLVER        | info    | CVODE BDF stability limit detection algorithm OFF\

Comment: Does the behavior depend on the communication stepsize when simulating the CS FMU?
The Communication points might force might force to the FMU respo. CVODE to take different stepsizes and re-initialize  which can lead to different bahavior than in the "native"simulation with CVODE

Comment: I am using fmpy to simulate the fmu from python. The stepsize I am using for the doStep() function is the same as I am using for the simulation in OMEdit. Does that answer your question?

Comment: The stepsize might have a different meaning for the FMU and in OMEdit: The FMU is forced to reach the communication point, while the "display stepsize" in OMEdit might not trigger these points to be reached, but only get interpolated values. 
What happens if you trigger a a simulation of the FMU with one very large timestep corresponding to reaching the endtime of your simulation?